# Do I have to close FileOutputStream which is wrapped by PrintStream?

Tags: java, stream

I'm using `FileOutputStream` with `PrintStream` like this:

```
class PrintStreamDemo {  
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        FileOutputStream out; 
        PrintStream ps; // declare a print stream object
        try {
            // Create a new file output stream
            out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt");

            // Connect print stream to the output stream
            ps = new PrintStream(out);

            ps.println ("This data is written to a file:");
            System.err.println ("Write successfully");
            ps.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println ("Error in writing to file");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm closing only the `PrintStream`. Do I need to also close the `FileOutputStream` (`out.close();`)?

Comment: Check out the source code: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/PrintStream.java.html

Comment: By the way, the beauty of PrintStream is the fact you can use it with just a String (for the filename) or a File object. You do not need to open a FOStream just to use it in the PrintStream.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, you only need to close the outermost stream. It will delegate all the way to the wrapped streams.

However, your code contains one conceptual failure, the close should happen in `finally`, otherwise it's never closed when the code throws an exception between opening and closing.

E.g.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException { 
    PrintStream ps = null;

    try {
        ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt"));
        ps.println("This data is written to a file:");
        System.out.println("Write successfully");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error in writing to file");
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) ps.close();
    }
}
```

*(note that I changed the code to **throw** the exception so that you understand the reason of the problem, the exception namely contains detailed information about the cause of the problem)*

Or, when you're already on Java 7, then you can also make use of ARM (Automatic Resource Management; also known as [try-with-resources](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)) so that you don't need to close anything yourself:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException { 
    try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt"))) {
        ps.println("This data is written to a file:");
        System.out.println("Write successfully");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error in writing to file");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: When i add finally block and try to do `ps.close()` in there i get error: `variable ps might not have been initialized`

Comment: You need to initialize it with `null`.

Comment: Note that I updated the answer with a Java 7 example which is more terse.

Answer (score 8):

No , here is implementation of `PrintStream`'s `close()` method:

```
public void close() {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (! closing) {
        closing = true;
        try {
            textOut.close();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
            trouble = true;
        }
        textOut = null;
        charOut = null;
        out = null;
        }
    }
```

You can see `out.close();` which closes output stream.

Answer (score 6):

No, according to the javadoc, the close method will [close](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#close%28%29) the underlying stream for you.

Answer (score 6):

No you dont need to. PrintStream.close method automatically closes the underlining output stream.

Check the API.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#close%28%29

Answer (score -2):

No. It is not require to close other components. when you close stream it automatically close other related component.