# Stream writer on char[] does not work

Tags: java, stream, writer

I have the following code, but the char[] cc does not seem to get written when I checked the output file.  Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
import java.io.*;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("start of main\n");
    char[] cc = new char[300];
    try {
      String s = "this is a test.";
      System.arraycopy(s.toCharArray(), 0, cc, 0, s.length());
      System.out.printf("cc = %s\n", new String(cc));
      String filename = "tst.data";
      DataOutputStream ostream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
      OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(ostream);
      writer.write(cc, 0, 300);
      ostream.close();

      DataInputStream istream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
      InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(istream);
      char[] newcc = new char[300];
      reader.read(newcc, 0, 300);
      istream.close();

      System.out.printf("newcc = %s\n", new String(newcc));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.printf("Exception - %s\n", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are making it more complicated by using char[] when you don't really need that, at least in this given code. You can do everything above by just using String

Answer (score 3):

You need to close the outermost I/O wrapper.

Replace

```
ostream.close();
```

by

```
writer.close();
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, those `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` wrappers are unnecessary in this context. Remove them. Finally, you should be closing the streams in a `finally` block. See also this related question: [Do I have to close FileOutputStream which is wrapped by PrintStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080649/do-i-have-to-close-fileoutputstream-which-is-wrapped-by-printstream)

Comment: but what i really want is to use ostream to writeInt after writer writing out the array.  If write.close is called, then how does ostream keeps writing afterwards.  Of course writer does not support write(int).

Comment: If you close `ostream`, how would you do a `writeInt()` on it anyway? Just do it after calling `writer.flush()` and before calling `writer.close()`. By the way, what's the functional requirement? I can't help having the impression that you're not really understanding the purpose of `DataInput/OutputStream` and/or are overcomplicating simple things.

Comment: but this does not work. I can write(int) with ostream before calling writer.close(), but then it caused IOException when I try to read it back.

Comment: I understand the problem. But I do still not understand the functional requirement. We can keep cobbling a bad solution together, but that's not my style. You might want to ask a new question about that wherein you clearly describe the functional requirement and ask how to solve it the best, wherein you show the failed attempts.

Comment: i am trying to write(char[]) and then write(int) afterwards.  But DataOutputStream does not have write(char[]), it only has write(String).  But I want to write a fixed number of characters (as a byte array), not just the length of the string.

Comment: You can't violate the protocol of DataOutputStream by sneaking around it.

Comment: Well, you likely need to use `writeUTF()` and `readUTF()` methods respectively. You can convert `char[]` to `String` and vice versa by its constructor and the `toCharArray()` method. You only need to get rid of the `Writer` and `Reader` from your code and stick to `DataOutput/InputStream` methods.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that writer still not flush buffer to ostream.
You can use writer.flush();
like this

```
writer.write(cc, 0, 300);
writer.flush();
```