# Write at the end of a file

Tags: java, file

I want to write in file the content of a list. The code is easy to understand and sometimes do the work. But the most of the times it fails. This is what i've tried so far :

```
public void finishTheTest(String outputFileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
        StringBuilder testOutPutStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            if(!isFieldSuccessFull) {
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append("Error for Task  -> " + tm.getFieldHM(tm.getKey()));
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append("*****************************************");
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                for(String str : listFailure) {
                    testOutPutStringBuilder.append(str);
                    testOutPutStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append("*****************************************");
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            if(!isCinematicSuccessFull) {
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append("Error for Repository -> " + tm.getFieldHM(tm.getKey()));
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append("*****************************************");
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append("Cinematic error.");
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append("*****************************************");
                testOutPutStringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            try(PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( new FileOutputStream(outputFileName, true))) {
                System.out.println(testOutPutStringBuilder);
            ps.println(testOutPutStringBuilder.toString());
        }
```

I'm browsing a list of String to build a StringBuilder or i simply append String to the StringBuilder. Then i print it on the standard output, wich is working and then i print it in the specified file. The file is created but most of the time it stays empty even after the execution of the code. Since i specified "true" at the creation of the FileOutputStream, i hoped that the text would simply add at the end at the file. But when i run the code more than once i have nothing left in the file.

Is there something that i'm missing ?

Comment: any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: No there is no exception

Comment: Did you check if `testOutPutStringBuilder.toString().isEmpty()` is true?

Comment: yes i check when i put sysout it on the standard output.

Comment: In my computer, your code run without any problem. Can you provide more information? Such as 1st time input, 2nd time input, etc...

Comment: Did you run it more than one time ? Because i just run it 3 times in a row and it was successfull.

Comment: What do you mean by 1st time input ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using try-with-resources, which leaves open the possibility of **Suppressed Exceptions**:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html

If you look at the accepted answer here

[Do I have to close FileOutputStream which is wrapped by PrintStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080649/do-i-have-to-close-fileoutputstream-which-is-wrapped-by-printstream)

you can add a `catch` block to see if some exception is happening that you're missing.

You could temporarily change your code to something like this:

```
public void finishTheTest(String outputFileName) throws Exception {
  ...
  try(PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( new FileOutputStream(outputFileName, true))) {
    System.out.println(testOutPutStringBuilder);
    ps.println(testOutPutStringBuilder.toString());
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error in writing to file:");
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;        
  }
  ...
}
```

then you will see any exception if it is thrown by your `try()`.

Comment: I've just read the doc part about the suppressed exception. As i understand it, if there is more than one exception thrown by the block, then only one exception will be thrown. I don't think i'm in that case since i' don't have any exception fired.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem. Instead of using this to write to my file :

```
try(PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( new FileOutputStream(outputFileName, true))) {
            ps.println(testOutPutStringBuilder.toString());
}
```

I'm using this :

```
try(PrintWriter ps = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFileName, true)))) {
            ps.println(testOutPutStringBuilder.toString());

        }
```

This is working every time from a while now. I still don't know what was wrong with the other code.