# should i close FileOutputStream which is wrapped by ZipOutputStream

Tags: java, zip, fileoutputstream

I'm writing a batch process , where below will be called in a loop for large number of times. So i'm trying to find out if i'm closing the resource properly

// This will be called in a loop

```
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ZipOutputStream zos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
     ...
     ...
     closeQuietly(zos)
     } catch(Exception e) {log.error(e.getMessage(),e);}

void closeQuietly(ZipOutputStream zos) {
        try {
            zos.closeEntry();
            zos.flush();
            zos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {log.error(e.getMessage(),e);}
    }
```

Am i closing the resource properly. and do i also need to close `FileOutputStream` in `closeQuietly()`

Comment: I would advise you to read this [Oracle Document](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-statements.html#472) about your code style, and your answer might be here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8080685/4697963

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) you'll find out that .close() "Closes the ZIP output stream as well as the stream being filtered."

so you should be fine the way you do it

Answer (score 1):

It also can be reached by try with resources, something like

```
  try (
      fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)
    ) {
    your code  
    
 }
```